# Create and register user in jhipster for testcase

Tags: testing, registration, jhipster

I want to create users in my jhipster application for unittests. I have done this with userService.createUserInformation(...), but the user seems to be not registered afterwards. Does anyone know how to create and register the user for my tests?

Thank you

Best regards

Markus

Comment: Spring Security 4.0 provides some annotations to make testing easier. See http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/04/spring-security-4 for more information. JHipster upgraded to 4.0 in its 2.7.0 release: http://jhipster.github.io/2015/04/03/jhipster-release-2.7.0.html

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks a lot, I give it a try